# What is Adios Bruce Lee?

Tags: 20th-century, popular-culture, media

A co-worker of mine came in wearing a shirt with this image on it:

[image]

This looks like a movie poster, but I'd never heard of that particular [Bruce Lee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_Lee) movie, so I tried looking it up. As near as I can tell, there is no such movie in his [Filmography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_Lee_filmography).

So what exactly is the story behind this poster?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Adios** is Spanish for **Farewell** or **Goodbye**.

This is a [**cloned poster**](http://www.benitomovieposter.com/catalog/adios-bruce-lee-p-32524.html?language=en) made in Argentina of the  movie, from the [Bruceploitation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruceploitation) movement of the 1970's, *[**Goodbye Bruce Lee: His Last Game of Death**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0073061/)*. This movie is actually a cloned version of the **original movie** [**Game of Death**.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_of_Death)  It was released in 1975, two years after Bruce Lee's death. And starred **[Bruce Li](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_Li)** (Don't confuse him with [Bruce Le](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_Le)). Hence this movie doesn't features in filmography of [Bruce Lee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_Lee) but features in [Bruce Li](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_Li)'s.

The director's name written  in the poster is **Lin Pin**  but according to **IMDb**, it's [**Pin Lin**](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1079052/) and according to **clonesofbrucelee** it's [**Lin Bing**](http://www.clonesofbrucelee.co.uk/goodbyebruceguide.html).

The story behind this poster, just guessing, may be the [Bruceploitation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruceploitation) movement of the 1970's.

Comment: I have a vague memory of a promotional short for Bruce Li from the 70's. The general gist was that he was going to be the next Bruce Lee.

Comment: Pin Lin/Lin Pin thing between the poster and IMDb could be related to confusion with the Chinese practice of writing their names Last Name -> First Name e.g. Deng Nan being the daughter of Deng Xiaoping.

Answer (score 1):

Bruce Lee was a Martial Arts instructor who was also a successful actor that popularized Martial Arts in the United States through film. This popularity extended to Latin America as well. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_Lee

"Adios Bruce Lee" is a tribute to him because of his untimely death, at the age of 32 from brain swelling brought about by an allergy or reaction to a particular medication. It was made by an Argentinian producer, and Adios means goodbye.